# Update append duplicate records in SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the below query and results. Can anyone help me how to write it using on update query so those duplicate can be rename like ELA1 `(ELA1)~1`,`(ELA1)~2`,`(ELA1)~3`

Query:

```
SELECT        
    Id, DisplayName
FROM  
    AbpOrganizationUnits
WHERE        
    (TenantId = 1) 
    AND (DisplayName IN (SELECT DisplayName
                         FROM AbpOrganizationUnits
                         WHERE (TenantId = 1)
                         GROUP BY DisplayName
                         HAVING (COUNT(DisplayName) > 1)))
ORDER BY 
    DisplayName, Id
```

Result:

```
Id  DisplayName
--------------------
294 ELA1 (ELA1)
295 ELA1 (ELA1)
299 ELA1 (ELA1)
292 ELA2 (ELA2)
293 ELA2 (ELA2)
285 ELA3 (ELA3)
286 ELA3 (ELA3)
302 ELA4 (ELA4)
303 ELA4 (ELA4)
279 ELA5 (ELA5)
304 ELA5 (ELA5)
290 ELAK (ELAK)
291 ELAK (ELAK)
296 Math1 (Math1)
301 Math1 (Math1)
299 Math2 (Math2)
300 Math2 (Math2)
283 Math3 (Math3)
284 Math3 (Math3)
288 Math4 (Math4)
289 Math4 (Math4)
282 Math5 (Math5)
287 Math5 (Math5)
297 MathK (MathK)
298 MathK (MathK)
309 Sci1 (Sci1)
310 Sci1 (Sci1)
305 Sci2 (Sci2)
306 Sci2 (Sci2)
311 Sci3 (Sci3)
312 Sci3 (Sci3)
313 Sci4 (Sci4)
314 Sci4 (Sci4)
280 Sci5 (Sci5)
281 Sci5 (Sci5)
307 SciK (SciK)
308 SciK (SciK)
```

Comment: @MaxSzczurek Result section shows all data in the table

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) and the [ROW_NUMBER window function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/).

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DisplayName ORDER BY id) rownum
    FROM dbo.AbpOrganizationUnits
)
UPDATE dbo.AbpOrganizationUnits 
SET DisplayName = DisplayName + '~' + CAST(cte.rownum AS VARCHAR(25))
FROM dbo.AbpOrganizationUnits 
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.id = AbpOrganizationUnits.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ou.*,
             row_number() over (partition by displayname) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by displayname) as cnt
      from AbpOrganizationUnits ou
      where tenantid = 1
     )
update toupdate
    set displayname = concat(displayname, '~', seqnum)
    where cnt >= 2;
```